# TypeScript ReactNAtive Error "MaterialTopTabNavigationOptions only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here"

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'm trying to create a TopTab in React Natibe and I followd some lesson online now after creating my .tsx file and imported the necessary dependancies I got error trying to import some dependancies I realized this error has to do with Typescript but i don't know why i'm getting the error or how to solve the problem. Even some of my import seems to be unused even though i'm referring to them. Below is the code producing the error

```
import{createMaterialTopTabNavigator,
MaterialTopTabNavigationOptions,
MaterialTopTabNavigationEventMap} from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';
import {TabNavigationState, ParamListBase} from '@react-navigation/native';
import { withLayoutContext } from 'expo-router';

const {Navigator} = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

export const MaterialTopTabs = withLayoutContext<
  MaterialTopTabNavigationOptions,
  typeof Navigator,
  TabNavigationState<ParamListBase>,
  MaterialTopTabNavigationEventMap
>(Navigator);

export default function Layout() {
  return (
    <MaterialTopTabs>
        <MaterialTopTabs.Screen />
    </MaterialTopTabs>
  )
}
```

Below is a screenshot of the code and the error from TS

[image]

Comment: Your code seems okay. Have you made sure it's not an LSP problem by restarting your editor? Does it fail also at compile or is the error only present in the editor?

Comment: @Anthony Bertrand
 it's an editor error and has now being resolved, thanks